# EF InsertOrUpdate issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't have any problem when inserting into the database, but when I did the update process, the following issues emerge.

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'kgSoft_Pro.ORM.Models.StokKarti' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

AddOrUpdate Code

```
public int InsertOrUpdate(T Entity) 
{
    var type = Entity.GetType();
    var property = type.GetProperty("id");
    var propValue = (int)property.GetValue(Entity);
    dbContext.Entry(Entity).State = propValue > 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    return Save();
}
```

Save Codes

```
StokKarti stok = new StokKarti();
stok.Adi = txtStokAdi.Text;
stok.AlisFiyati = decimal.Parse(clcAlisFiyati.EditValue.ToString());
stok.StokKodu = btnStokKodu.EditValue.ToString();
stok.Barkod = txtBarkod.Text;
stok.DigerSatis = decimal.Parse(clcDigerFiyat.EditValue.ToString());
stok.GrupKod = lkGrupKodlari.EditValue.ToString();
stok.hizlisatis = chkSatisEkrani.Checked;
stok.PerakendeSatis = decimal.Parse(clcPerakende.EditValue.ToString());
stok.ToptanSatis =decimal.Parse(clcToptanFiyat.EditValue.ToString());
stok.RiskLimiti = (int?)txtRiskLimiti.EditValue ?? 0;
stok.KdvOrani = (int)lkKdvOran.EditValue;
stok.Birim = lkBirim.EditValue.ToString();
stok.Marka = lkMarkasi.EditValue.ToString();
stok.id = id;
sk.InsertOrUpdate(stok);
```

Comment: The entity Framework 6, this property are unfortunately not.

Comment: Where does `dbContext` come from? What is its life cycle?

Comment: I solved the problem. [code] dbContext.DbSet<T>().AddOrUpdate(Entity) [code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbContext.DbSet<T>().AddOrUpdate(Entity)
```

problem solved

Comment: [and new problem introduced!](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)